# Understand and correct the Recursive Function output

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have following function which prints the key whoes value is set.

But it is not returning the value as in array, rather when i print it using echo in foreach loop it shows the correct execution.

```
$array = [
    '1' => true,
    ['2' => false, '4' => true],
    '3' => true    
];

$arraytrueElements = array_function($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arraytrueElements);

function array_function($arr){
    $i=0;
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
             array_function($val);
        }else{
            if($val == true){
            $str[$key] = $key;
            echo "{$key}" .", \t";
        }
    }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Output,
1, 4, 3,

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 3
)
```

Expected output,

Output,
1, 4, 3,

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1,
    [4] => 4,
    [3] => 3
)
```

when I Modify the line of code  to this , `$str[$key] = array_function($val);`

then I have an array with all values, but why to add it if already in echo it is showing and getting assigned in $str array.
somewhat like this as an array element inside the array, not as in expected array output.

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => 4
        )
    [3] => 3
)
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. Please state exactly what you're trying to get, given what kind of input, with examples. Do you want to recursively grab all array keys whose value is exactly `true`?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `array_merge`:

```
function array_function($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ( is_array($val) ) {
             $result = array_merge($result, array_function($val));
        } elseif ( $val === true ) {
            $result[$key] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

An other way consists to write your function as a procedure with a reference to the result array:

```
function array_function($arr, &$result) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ( is_array($val) ) {
             array_function($val, $result);
        } elseif ( $val === true ) {
            $result[$key] = $key;
        }
    }
}

$result = [];
array_function($arr, $result);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive) to loop over each value/key pair and keep only the desired keys:

```
$matches = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$matches) {
  if ($value === true) {
    $matches[] = $key;
  }
});

print_r($matches);  // [1, 4, 3]
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/Ksq4F**

Comment: Jeto, I do not want to use in built functionality of recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't / won't use library functions such as `array_walk_recursive` or `array_merge`, you may use something like this instead:

```
function findKeysWithTrueValues(array $array): array
{
  $matches = [];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      foreach (findKeysWithTrueValues($value) as $match) {
        $matches[] = $match;
      }
    } elseif ($value === true) {
      $matches[] = $key;
    }
  }
  return $matches;
}
```

This builds a `$matches` array of each set of keys in the array. If the value is an array, it loops over its own matches by doing a recursive call and adds every match. Otherwise, it just adds the key.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/42tX2**

Comment: Hi Jeto, the output is correct, I appreciate it, but again we are using built in function of array_merge, since I am learning or practicing php basics, want to avoid it.
I could write custom function for array_merge but any alternate or any trick logic.

Comment: @Sam I just edited my answer, check it out. This doesn't use `array_merge` now. Also please edit your opening question and make it more clear that you don't want any solutions that uses these built-in functions.